# What is a "cohomological type" automorphic representation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

Sorry for asking such a question. This is supposedly a well known definition for experts. However as an non-expert, I tried (very hard) google, Mathscinet etc, but still couldn't find a satisfactory resource.

What I want to know is the basic definitions, as well as the basic properties of such representations. Supposedly, there should be a book or some expository notes about this notion?

Thank you and I apologize again.

Comment: See the first chapter of http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~bergeron/Travaux_files/LivreBergeronClozel_versiondefinitive.pdf (in French). For more complete (but less user-friendly) information you should go to the book of A. Borel and N. Wallach http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Borel&s5=wallach&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=1721403